# What was the first hierarchical file system?

Tags: history

"Directories containing directories and files" seems to have been around forever, but there must have been a first.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I think Multics introduced the [first hierarchical filesystem](http://www.multicians.org/fjcc4.html) and presented it at the 1965 Fall Joint Computer Conference.  (The reference is one of the papers from that conference, describing the filesystem.)

Unix of course also has an hierarchical filesystem, which it seems to have inherited from Multics.

The [wikipedia article on Unix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix) says:

> Unix also popularized the hierarchical file system with arbitrarily nested subdirectories, originally introduced by Multics. Other common operating systems of the era had ways to divide a storage device into multiple directories or sections, but they had a fixed number of levels, often only one level. Several major proprietary operating systems eventually added recursive subdirectory capabilities also patterned after Multics. DEC's RSX-11M's "group, user" hierarchy evolved into VMS directories, CP/M's volumes evolved into MS-DOS 2.0+ subdirectories, and HP's MPE group.account hierarchy and IBM's SSP and OS/400 library systems were folded into broader POSIX file systems.

The earliest hierarchical file system with which I had personal experience at the time of its release was [ODS-2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Files-11#History), introduced with VMS in 1979.

Comment: Multicians are a loyal bunch, even to this day.  Here is a link for Multics http://www.multicians.org

Comment: On his WWW home page (http://www.csl.sri.com/users/neumann/) Peter Neumann, the author of the paper linked above, lists Albert Einstein as one of his mentors and as his inspiration for hierarchical abstractions, and he further relates this idea directly to its application in Multics.

Answer (score 14):

An early hierarchical file system was developed for the Electronic Recording  Machine Accounting (ERMA) Mark  1, as presented in this 1958 Eastern Joint Computer Conference paper
[Organization Generated  in and  Retrieval  of  Records a  Large-Scale  Engineering Project by G.A. Barnard III and L. Fein](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/1458043.1458058):

> [image: fig 2, fig 3]
>
> Fig.  3  is  self-explanatory.  It   shows the  arrangement  of the
> records in the  file  folders.
>
> This  file  system is  "closed"  in
> the  sense  that   it  is  bounded  by  the   decimally  integral
> coding of categories from 00 to  100  and  by  an  exahustive
> listing  of  generic attributes   and  categories.  However,  it  is
> expandable in the  sense that,  when necessary.  new  entries  are
> permitted  within  the   subcategories  and  parameters   without
> resorting to modification of the  original  file  structure.
> For example,  categories  test  equipment-51,  external  equipment-52, and
> tools-53, were added later  in the   only  reasonable  location;  in
> the   50  series, auxiliary equipment.  This  method of adding new
> categories to the  file  can be  likened to the  use of the  familiar
> accordian file  in  which  a  suitable   pocket   can  be  stretched
> to  fit  new  material,  but   the  structure  of the  containing
> folds of the  file  and its  major   pockets remain unchanged;  This
> is  in contrast  to  a  file  of  rigid  construction in which  the
> only  recourse  for  addition is to append material  or  to make  a
> new  container.

Comment: Great to have a link to the actual paper!

Comment: This is a mostly paper-based system, though it is possible Neumann was aware of it.

Answer (score 1):

IBM developed IMS in 1966, but I think you're looking for something simpler than that

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_Information_Management_System

Answer (score 0):

I am by no means sure about this information, but wasn't the ICL system for storing on high speed drums (concrete cored) a hierarchical system? This is at about the same time as the ICL CAFS system which (like Don's answer) was first introduced in 1965.

**EDIT**

The ICL system may fall into the category (described by Don from the Wikipedia article ) as having a fixed number of levels. I don't know where to find the information to resolve whether or not it was truly hierarchical. The ICL system was developed from the LEO range (of several companies that were combined to form ICL) which did not (AFAIK) have any persistent storage - being reliant on mercury delay lines for temporary storage.

Comment: For anyone not familiar, ICL's CAFS is a whole different idea that also comes from the 1960s, and was first prototyped in the early 1970s.  CAFS stands for Content Addressable File Store.

Comment: I believe the first hierarchical file system from ICL was in the GEORGE 3 OS and it was apparently inspired by Multics.